# Using (int) sqrt(N) causes 'array bound is not an integer constant'

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int size = (int) sqrt(4);
int arr[size];

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

and I got:

```
test.c:5: error: array bound is not an integer constant
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: You can not declare arrays of size which is not known at compile time.

Comment: this is why you see `#defines` used so frequently in C-programs

Comment: IMO, `int size = (int) sqrt(4);` shouldn't even compile if `size` is a global/static variable.

Comment: use clang to compile your code, it gives you error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant, C syntax does not support compile-time constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int arr[size];
```

This defines an array with a constant size. But `size` was computed by a call to `sqrt`, so it's not a constant according to how C programs are executed.

The compiler needs to know how big the array is to create the global memory layout of the program. So the `sqrt` can't be deferred until runtime. And C doesn't have any concept of a "math" function that can be resolved at compile time.

The only way through this is to perform the calculation yourself and put the result (`2`) directly into the source code.

Comment: Hmm, no upvotes after a few minutes. Is there something wrong with this answer? I know I'm not covering C99 but I think that feature is still a bit obscure and unportable…

Comment: No actually you described very beautifully.

Answer (score 5):

You can't define arrays with static storage (for example "global" arrays) with variable size. Should the array have auto storage (if it were an array in a function) it would work as a VLA.

As icepack correctly notes, VLAs were formally introduced in C99.

Comment: Should be noted - only in C99

Answer (score -1):

```
const int size=(int) sqrt(4);
```

A precalculated constant will do. You will not, however, be able to change neither the array size nor this constant.

Comment: Pitiful. I thought C preprocessor is smart enough to evaluate constant expressions.

Comment: `sqrt` isn't constant expression